# How to efficiently compute co-occurrence counts over many lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python 3.8 and need to efficiently compute the cooccurrence counts of numbers in a list of lists.

I have the following array:

```
x = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 11, 4, 4], ...]
```

I want to compute a cooccurrence matrix like so:

```
C[i][j] = # freq(i) * freq(j) summed over all lists k in x
```

I currently have vectorized the computation for each list in x like so:

```
for l in x:
  freqs = np.bincount(l, minlength=SIZE)
  C[freqs > 0] += np.outer(freqs[freqs != 0], freqs)
```

The problem is I see no way to vectorize this outer loop. I also don't see a way to speed it up easily through parallelism. C can have ~1B entries so merge-type parallelism will be tough on memory.

Is there anyway to speed this up?

Note: x can have ~2.5M lists and C can have sides 75k (unique elements)

Comment: Do you have a NxM array (which you can represent using an numpy ndarray), or like your example suggests just a list of lists with differing lengths?

Comment: just a list of lists with differing lengths. x can have 2M+ elements so an NxM array would be too large

Comment: So you probably cannot easily vectorize it by using `numpy`, then. You can try `numba` if you want to stick to Python.

Comment: As each iteration of the outer loop carries significant payload vectorizing will not save you much because overhead to work ratio is already small.